# Fixed size tape Turing machine which cannot write on input is equivalent to DFA

Tags: computer-science, automata, formal-languages

I have to prove that Turing machine with fixed size tape which cannot write on input is equivalent to finite automaton (DFA or NFA).

It's important to add that the size of the tape is the size of the tape which excludes the input. 
For example, if the input's size is n so the tape's size would be k+n, where k is the length of the tape that excludes the input.

I understand the main idea but it is super hard to prove it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

We can see that you can emulate a DFA on such a Turing Machine - the Turing Machine just has read-only states and consumes one character of input on each step - essentially implementing a DFA on a Turing Machine. This is the easy direction.

Showing that you can emulate the TM on the DFA is a bit harder, but comes down to the fact that there are only `k` possible places to write `m` characters, where `m` is the size of the writing alphabet of the machine. Therefore your TM has only `k^m` possible tape states in addition to however many states the machine has, which we'll call `n`. So a DFA with `n*k^m` states can cover the TM's states.

Obviously this is a handwavy sketch of a proof. You can take it from here.

Comment: I know it, but I'm having a super hard time to prove it formally.. what technique would you use to prove it? writing the algorithm for the Turing machine? creating formally the automaton and prove using induction?

Comment: I would formally define what the DFA states are and show they have a one-to-one correspondence with the TM states and the state of the write part of its tape. Then show that each modification to the TM's state is replicated in a corresponding transition in the DFA.

Comment: aren't there k^m tape states?